# Is there any method like substitute of MooTools in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, mootools, substitution

This is MooTools code:

```
var myString = "{subject} is {property_1} and {property_2}.";
var myObject = {subject: 'Jack Bauer', property_1: 'our lord', property_2: 'savior'};
myString.substitute(myObject);
```

Does jQuery has this method or similar?

Comment: http://www.planabc.net/2011/05/31/simple_javascript_template_substitute/
https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/src/substitute/js/substitute.js Here is YUI's solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but there's nothing preventing you from adding it yourself:

```
jQuery.substitute = function(str, sub) {
    return str.replace(/\{(.+?)\}/g, function($0, $1) {
        return $1 in sub ? sub[$1] : $0;
    });
};

// usage:
jQuery.substitute('{foo}', {foo:'123'});
```

Comment: For reference, this is how the MooTools substitute works:
`substitute: function(object, regexp){
        return String(this).replace(regexp || (/\\?\{([^{}]+)\}/g), function(match, name){
            if (match.charAt(0) == '\\') return match.slice(1);
            return (object[name] != null) ? object[name] : '';
        });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin https://github.com/trix/nano , the source is just a few lines

```
/* Nano Templates (Tomasz Mazur, Jacek Becela) */
(function($){
  $.nano = function(template, data) {
    return template.replace(/\{([\w\.]*)\}/g, function (str, key) {
      var keys = key.split("."), value = data[keys.shift()];
      $.each(keys, function () { value = value[this]; });
      return (value === null || value === undefined) ? "" : value;
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You can use dot notation {user.name} , just simple and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.nano` answer threw me for a loop because it errors if you have any typos in your template dot notation, and furthermore it doesn't allow all legal characters like `a['foo bar']` so below is my version as a `$.substitute` plugin:

```
/*
 * JQuery Substitute method allows for simple templating using JS Object dot notation.
 * Contribute link: https://gist.github.com/danielsokolowski/0954fc2a767f441720b9
 *
 * @param strTemplate - string contain the replacement tokens
 * @param objData   - an Object represetnting your replacmenet values
 *
 *  Example:
 * var strTemplate = 'Hello {user.name}'    
 * var strDatra = {'user': 'Daniel Sokolowski'}
 * alert($.substitute(strTemplate, objData)); // outputs 'Hello Daniel Sokolowski'
 *
 */
$.substitute = function(strTemplate, objData) {
    return strTemplate.replace(/\{([^{}]*)\}/g, function(math, subMatch1) {
        try {
            var keys = subMatch1.split(".");
            var value = objData[keys.shift()]; // return first element and update the original array
            while (keys.length !== 0) { // keep returning properties
                value = value[keys.shift()]
            }
            return String(value);
        } catch (err) { // return any errors as a string
            return String(value);
        }

    });
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the editing confusion, I just saw that you do a `split(".")` inside the plugin

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins that share a similar syntax to the String.Format method in .NET.

[This one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/jQuery.format) leverages the jQuery Validate plugin (commonly found on CDNs).

Example:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  var str = "Hello {0}, this is {1}";

  str = jQuery.validator.format(str, "World", "Bob");
  alert("'" + str + "'");
});
```

The second plugin is named [.NET Style String Format](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dotnet_string_formatting).

Example:

```
var result = $.format("Hello, {0}", "world");
```

These may not be exactly what you're looking for, but they may be useful.